# IBM Worklight 6.0 - jQuery Mobile page linking not working in the Android emulator

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Using Worklight 6.0, I have created an application with the Android environment and am using jQuery Mobile.

Page linking is perfectly working when previewing the application's Common environment via Worklight Console. But it's not working in the Android emulator. The same page is being refreshed whenever I click on the submit button.

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>SaskenV1</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SaskenV1.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.js"></script>
<link
    href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css"
    rel="stylesheet">


</head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
            <div data-role="page" id="page1">
                <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="fieldcontain">
                <label for="text">Username:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="name">
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="fieldcontain0">
                <label for="text0">Password:</label><input type="text"
                    name="text0" id="pass">

            </div>

            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="cancel">Cancel</a>
</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">

                    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" id="submit">Submit</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="SaskenV3.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <h6>2nd Page</h6>
        <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Go back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page1">Return to Page 1</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>Footer Content</h2>
    </div>
</div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>

            <script src="js/SaskenV1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I want to go to the #page2 whenever the user taps on the submit button. Have no idea why it's not working...

Update:

Now, I found that whatever changes I make in the html file is not affecting the Android project at all. Even though I build that too.

Comment: Please describe the full steps you have taken - did you add the Android environment to your application? What do you do next?

Comment: Yes I have added the android environment. After that I did some changes in the main html file. But its not reflecting in the android Project. (i.e I cannot view the changes I`ve done in the Android emulator). Common console, it works fine. Do I have to do anything specially after making changes in the main html file to apply the changes for the android project too?

Comment: No. During build the changes you've done in Common and copied to the Android. You can verify this by navigating in the generated Android project - yourpoject\www\default\....

Comment: is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly fine for me.
I have done the following in Worklight 6.0.0.1:

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. During the application creation I chose to add jQuery Mobile. I have used jQuery Mobile v1.3.1 (at minimum I have added the images folder and the jquery.mobile-1.3.1 CSS and JS files)
3. Added the Android environment
4. In `myProject\apps\myApp\common\myApp.html` I have replaced the contents of the `BODY` element with that of yours (except for the 3 script references at the bottom, of course)
5. Right-clicked on the myApp folder and chose `Run As > Build All and Deploy`
6. Right-clicked on the generated Android project and chose `Run As > Android application`

The app then launched in the Android Emulator.
After entering some text and clicking on the Submit button the page transitioned to the second page.

Make sure you are following the above.

[image]